# MySQL query for rows where date is in this week

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I'm trying to query for all rows where an event has been completed THIS week, where weeks start on Sunday.  I've tried this query, but it doesn't seem to work (I've tried both CURDATE() and NOW(), not sure if that matters), I get no rows returned:

```
SELECT `TodoCompleted`.`day`, `TodoCompleted`.`date` FROM `todo_completed` AS
`TodoCompleted` WHERE `TodoCompleted`.`employee_id` = 'whatever' AND 
`TodoCompleted`.`completed` = 0 AND WEEK(`TodoCompleted`.`date`) = 'WEEK(NOW())'
```

I've also tried this, but it isn't what I'm looking for since it pulls records from the previous week:

```
AND `TodoCompleted`.`date` BETWEEN CURDATE()-INTERVAL 1 WEEK AND CURDATE()
```

I can't just get them all within an interval of a week, I need just THIS week (Sunday - Saturday).

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: maybe you have no employee_id that is `whatever` try it without employee_id comparison and see if you get results. and your `WEEK(NOW())` should not be in quotes

Comment: To solve your issue you'll probably need to find the date of last Sunday, and after that it'll be pretty straightforward. Try looking into `DATE_SUB()` function.

Comment: @spaceman Thanks for the idea!  I didn't do exactly that (with the DATE_SUB() function), but I decided to just get the date of last Sunday with the date() function in PHP rather than doing it with just MySQL.

Comment: You're welcome! If you said that you can use PHP earlier there would've been a lot more options :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [YEARWEEK()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek)

```
AND YEARWEEK(`TodoCompleted`.`date`) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE())
```

and remove the quotes around it.